# Using momentum Feynman rules

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I have the interaction Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}_{int}=-\frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi^{\dagger}\phi)^2$.

Now I have to write down the complete expression for the Feyman diagram 
[image]

I also have included the momenta of each line...

According to momentum conservation I have

$p_5-p_2-p_3-p_4 = 0$ and $-p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=0$. From $k_1=p_5$ and $-k_2=p_1$ follows:

$k_1-p_2-p_3-p_4=0$ and $k_2+p_2+p_3+p_4=0$.

Now I have to calculate the number of needed Integrations...Using the famous formula $L=p-V+n=2$ I know that I need two integrations (two Loops)

My result is now:

$$\widetilde{G}(k_1,k_2) =\frac{(-\lambda i)^{2}}{2}\frac{i}{k_1^{2}-m^{2}+i\epsilon}\frac{i}{k_2^{2}-m^{2}+i\epsilon}\int\frac{d^{4}p_2}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{d^{4}p_4}{(2\pi)^{4}}\frac{i^2}{[p_2^{2}-m^2-i\epsilon]\cdot [(k_1-p_2-p_4)^{2}-m^2-i\epsilon)]}\frac{i^2}{[p_4^{2}-m^2-i\epsilon]\cdot [(k_1-p_2-p_4)^{2}-m^2-i\epsilon)]}$$

where I have allready include the symmetry factor...

Does this looks right?

Comment: You have 3 internal lines but 4 propagators with loop moments?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Oh.... I integrate twice over the line with momentum p3 right?

Comment: No. You have 2 integration variables as you should as there are 2 loops, but you have 4 propagators but only 3 internal lines.